# PYQT4 Cell color

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to set a color to a cell.

This is a small sample of my code:

```
self.tableWidget.setItem(1,8,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("test)) # this works fine
```

I have tried to

```
self.tableWidget.item(1,8,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem.setBackgroundColor("NOT SURE HERE")) # want cell to red
```

What is the best way I can get the cell the color of red and still see the word "test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate a `QTableWidgetItem` and set the color first:

```
item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("test")
item.setBackground(QtCore.Qt.red)
self.tableWidget.setItem(1,8,item)
```